# Does AWS Greengrass support the Go runtime for functions at the edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I'd like to use the Go runtime for Greengrass lambda functions at the edge but it looks like Java is the closest support. Is there a way to provide your own runtime for this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no unfortunately at present. You can find the supported runtimes here;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/lambda-functions.html

[image: Supported runtimes]